# f.select, passing an id, but showing a name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to have a form, in which user can select two players from a list (two separate select fields).
Later, in controller I need to find those two Player instances.
I know the only way to pass an object in a form is to use its id, but I obsiously can't make user select a raw number - I'd like to have ability to show players' names in a select box, but to somehow pass an id. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the Rails [`options_for_select` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select). This helper will present a human readable field from your model to the view while returning an id field from that same model through your `params` hash.

```
<%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(@users.collect { | user | [user.name, user.id] }, @user.id), {}, {} %>
```

You'll need to make sure that you have `@users` and `@user` defined in whichever controller method corresponds with the view using `options_for_select`. You'll obviously need both and `id` and a `name` field in your User model, otherwise, this helper will fail miserably.

Comment: Thank you, it was extremely hepful! I have just one more problem -  user can't select two exactly the same players - it can't be something like user1 vs user1. I was experimenting with disabled option, but without success, because list of available users should change dynamically after selecting first user, which probably can't be done...

Comment: @user568949 You're now asking a different question. If this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted so that future readers know what worked. Then post your new question as a new question. Please understand that Stack Overflow is meant for obtaining answers regarding specific programming questions. Adding new parameters to the question is asking answerers to hit a moving target, which becomes a dicey proposition under the best circumstances.